# How to add Info to custom keyword Log

Tags: robotframework

In Robot Framework, when you create a custom keyword using the `*** Keyword ***` section of .robot file, is there a way to print an `INFO` message in the log file? I've tried using BuiltIn.Log keyword, but it creates a new keyword section where the `INFO` is written.

I want to get `INFO` in custom keyword this way:
Info in Keyword execution

[image: Info in Keyword execution]

But currently, my only option is: Info inside BuiltIn.Log definition

[image: Info inside BuiltIn.Log definition]

Is there a way to add `INFO` directly to my custom keyword without using Python API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge what you are attempting, is unfortunately not doable. This way of embedding messages can be done by the `robot.logger` or Python's `logging` api - More info in the [Robot Framework User Guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#programmatic-logging-apis)

However in addition to using the `Log` keyword, you may alleviate the need by first adding a *documentation* string on your keywords - the first line is always shown in the `Documentation` section of the keyword. Additionally by enabling *Trace* on the log file you'll get at least the Arguments and Return values shown on each keyword.

The Documentation is added with the `[Documentation]` tag similar to

```
Custom Keyword
    [Documentation]    This string is shown completely until I leave at least
    ...    One empty row.
    ...
    ...    This is shown only in the library documentation file.
```

And logging modes are changed with a launch option `-L` or `--loglevel`, to enable Trace mode, simply add the option when launching your robot.

```
robot -t TestName -s SuiteName -L TRACE .\Path\to\Tests
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `Log to console  Typing text ${User} into text field 'username'`  like this?

Comment: ```Log To Console``` writes into the terminal, not the log. My concern is with the way the INFO message is located on the log